# Null Pointer Exception when passing Bitmap through Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap

I am trying to pass a BItmap[] from one activity to other using Intent.But, it is not getting passed,which in result is causing a Null Pointer Exception I guess. I am taking upto four images with the camera and storing them in a Bitmap[] ,which I am trying to pass to another activity.The logcat says the error is at line 94,which is where the passed Bitmap is used. Here's the code (only the relevant parts). Kindly help,Thanks in advance !

Take Pic.java :

the onCreateMethod:

```
         @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.takepic);
    initializeVar();
    storeInArray(images);
```

}

The onActivity result for the four imageViews (which start the Camera activity) :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        photo1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(photo1);
    } if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        photo2 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(photo2);
    } if(requestCode == 3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        photo3 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView3.setImageBitmap(photo3);
    } if(requestCode == 4 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        photo4 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView4.setImageBitmap(photo4);      
    }
}
```

The method to store the individual bitmaps in the array :

```
      private Bitmap[] storeInArray(Bitmap[] bitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(photo1 != null){
         bitmap[i]= photo1;
         i++;
    }if(photo2 != null){
        bitmap[i]= photo2;
         i++;
    }if(photo3 != null){
        bitmap[i]= photo3;
         i++;
    }if(photo4 != null){
        bitmap[i]= photo4;
         i++;
    }

    return bitmap;
 }
```

And finally, the onClickListener for the button :

```
      bCamEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(TakePic.this,NewEmail.class);
            i.putExtra("Image",images);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

And in the other Class:

```
       extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null)
        receive = (Bitmap[]) extras.getParcelableArray("Image");
```

and for the send email button :

```
       newSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            convertEditTextToString();
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"seemaswain.09@gmail.com");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,newSubject);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,newContent);

            newUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            for(String file : images) {
                File fileIn = new File(file);
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                newUris.add(u);
            }

            emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, newUris);
            startActivity(emailIntent);
        }
    });


}

public String[] BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap[]){
    int i=0;
     String[] temp= new String[2000];
    while(bitmap[i] !=null){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    temp[i]=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    i++;
    }
    return temp;
 }
```

Finally, the logcat :

```
     12-05 13:34:04.207: W/dalvikvm(3846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e62498)
     12-05 13:34:04.207: E/test(3846): Exception
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846): java.lang.NullPointerException
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at com.example.bethechange.NewEmail$1.onClick(NewEmail.java:94)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4106)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17150)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4792)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:808)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:575)
     12-05 13:34:04.227: E/AndroidRuntime(3846):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is not recommended to keep images with intent. Better save the image in a file and send the `path of the file` to next class.

Comment: The logcat says error occurs on NewEmail.java:94. which line is that ?

Comment: @sayed.jalil it is for(String file : images) { ..this line..

Comment: receive = (Bitmap[]) extras.getParcelableArray("Image"); You receive images into "receive" but you are iterating over "images". You sure ? you have assigned "receive" to "images" later ?

Comment: Make sure you have initialized your Bitmap[] with proper size!

Comment: @sayed.jalil yeah , i have. It seems the bitmap images aren't getting stored in the bitmap[].

Comment: @LalitPoptani You mean, like Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[size] ?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Now,it says there's a null pointer at this line :

receive = (Bitmap[]) extras1.getParcelableArrayExtra("Image"); What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass bitmap array to another activity by intent.
Bitmap maybe is big file.It will cause "TransactionTooLargeException"

You have 2 ways to fix this :

1: Use a global singleton(If bitmaps are temp data not exist in files)

2: Pass bitmap file path

Comment: I couldn't understand the first method. :/

Comment: Use a global singleton object ,then you can put your bitmap array in that object and access it through global object. Like this: DataCenter.getSingleton().getMyBitmaps()

Answer (score 0):

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);;

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        try {
             photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```